# compare NSString and integer?

Tags: ios, nsstring, integer

I have a string that I need to compare with an integer value.

I did this so far :

```
NSString *rad = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", combo.selectedText];
srchParam.radius = rad;
if (srchparam.radius > 5)
{
    //code here
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your first line is completely unnecessary - you're recreating the string itself, an extra function call for nothing. Why not simply `searchParam.radius = combo.selectedtext;`?

Comment: Is it weird storing a radius, which is obviously always a number, in a string. Change the type of srchParam.radius to an int, and convert it right away.

Comment: you can you the following 'srchParam.radius = [combo.selectedText intValue]' and then compare

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ([combo.selectedText intValue] > 5) {
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
srchParam.radius = [rad intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Comparing an NSString using the `<` operator will compare its memory address, not magically its contents (remember: Objective-C is not C++, there's no operator overloading). You have to compare the string's *numerical value* to the other integer using

```
if (([srchparam.radius intValue]) > 5)
{
     // code here
}
```

Also, please use whitespaces - your code will be nicer and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I guess radius is an integer here. Thus :

```
NSString *rad=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",combo.selectedText];
srchParam.radius =[rad intValue];
if((srchparam.radius)>5)
{
 //code here
}
```

Comment: @khadar : I saw what you wrote in your comment before you edited it.

Comment: I saw my colleague doing some thing in my comp. If it was any mistake, I'm sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *rad=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",combo.selectedText];
if([rad intValue]>5)
{
 //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats would be right!

```
if([[srchparam.radius] integerValue] > 5)
```

This example working in Xcode 4.5 with iOS SDK 6.0 if you still on Xcode 4.4 just change **integerValue** on **intValue**.